# Perl search string for pattern: *@enron.com

Tags: regex, perl, email

I'm searching a string for all valid e-mail addresses ending in @enron.com.

My assignment is the following line:

```
my $enronAddress =~/^(.+?)@\@enron\.com/i;
```

This isn't making any assignments, so I'm wondering what I've done wrong here.

Comment: I indented your code so it renders as code, hth.  Should there be two @ chars in there?

Comment: You probably need to start [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for all valid addresses within the string, or checking that the complete string is a valid address? I don't understand what you mean by "This isn't making any assignments" as all you have written is a regex pattern match

First of all you have two `@` signs in your pattern, which is clearly wrong

A lot depends on what you consider to be a valid email address, but for a start this will check whether the contents of `$enronAddress` is a valid address

```
if ( $enronAddress =~ /^[^@\s]+\@enron\.com$/i ) { ... }
```

and this will print all valid addresses that appear in `$enronAddress`

```
print "$_\n" for $enronAddress =~ /[^@\s]+\@enron\.com/gi;
```

Comment: I'm trying to pull out a valid e-mail address from a string, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're checking an uninitialized variable against a regular expression. This probably isn't what you want.

If you have an email address in `$address`, you'd do something like:

```
my $address = 'example@enron.com';
if ($address =~ /^(.+)\@enron\.com$/) {
  my $to = $1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not an assignment, it's comparing an uninitialized variable against a regex. Without more context, it is hard to fix your code, but for a start, put this at the top of your script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Do that in every new script you write from now on.

Then maybe something like

```
my $text = <>;
my $addr = $text if $text =~ /\@enron\.com$/;
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to match with a simple "end of string" regex first? Using Perl's debugger:

```
DB<3> x 'foo@enron.com' =~ /\@enron\.com$/
0  1

DB<4> x 'foo@enrn.com' =~ /\@enron\.com$/
empty array
```

Those show you're finding the right patterns. Then add a capture to it:

```
DB<5> x ($user) = ('foo@enron.com' =~ /(.+)\@enron.com$/)
0  'foo'

DB<6> x $user
0  'foo'
```

In code it'd look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my ($user) = ('foo@enron.com' =~ /(.+)\@enron\.com$/);
print "$user\n";
```